# Problem with li class image swap and jQuery slide on mouseover

Tags: jquery, image, hover, slide, swap

Sorry if this is misleading, I'm fairly new at Java-script and jQuery.  Can anyone tell me how to make a navigation link slide left on mouseover and slide back on mouseout? The li classes I am trying to individually slide on mouseover are used in this [gallery image swap](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/) script.  I have a left navigation plane with images that will change the corresponding image to the right on hover.

```
<script type>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Image swap on hover
    $("#gallery ul li img").hover(function(){
      $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/',    
      '')).stop().hide().fadeTo("slow",1);
    });
    // Image preload
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery ul li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
</script>
```

li classes contained within`$("#gallery ul li img").hover(function(){` are what I want to slide indvidually on mouseover and back on mouseout.  Ive tried

```
$("##gallery ul li img").hover(function(){
   $("gallery ul.home", this).stop().animate({left:"150px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
}, function() {
   $("gallery ul.home", this).stop().animate({right:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
```

But this seems to break `.hover(function(){`

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
<img src="images/gallery/home.png" alt="" id="main-img" />
  <ul>
   <li class="home"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" alt="" /></li>
   <li class="about"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/About Us.png" alt="" /></li>
   <li class="contact"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" alt="" /></li>
   <li class="services"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#body #left_nav #gallery #main-img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 20px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
}
#body #left_nav #links #gallery ul li{
    display: inline;
    clip: rect(auto,3px,auto,auto);
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
}
#body #left_nav #gallery ul .home {
    position: absolute;
    left: 117px;
    top: 74px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#body #left_nav #gallery ul .about {
    position: absolute;
    left: 88px;
    top: 176px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#body #left_nav #gallery ul .contact {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 277px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#body #left_nav #gallery ul .services {
    position: absolute;
    top: 385px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 98px;
}
```

Comment: A suggestion : when posting something like this give us a reference on jsfiddle it could be easier to test large parts of code ;)

Comment: You've got atleast one syntax error i'm assuming this is just a typo? (your hover function is missing `});` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your hover:

```
$("#gallery ul li img").hover(function(){
      $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/',''))
          .stop()
          .show("slide");
    },function(){
      $('#main-img').stop().hide("slide");
});
```

Also make sure you have the jquery ui script on your page otherwise this won't work.

and your preload needs to be:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(index) {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this[index];
    });
};
```

**EDIT** Thought I'd give you some light reading: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

**EDIT 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/kFBby/5/ jsFiddle with added animation.

Comment: Thanks, very useful stuff.  Here's an example of my site http://testsite00.hostoi.com/.  I basically want to have the links on the left slide left corresponding to the fade onmouse effect you see with the images on the right.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @dcd018 thoughts? ... I think that sounds like too much is happening at the same time. When do you want all this to happen? Just put an extra line in the function(s) and they should happen at the same time.